# Postgresql, get string after multiple ':' character

Tags: postgresql

I have the following column with entries

```
01:02:02:02
02:01:100:300
128:02:12:02
```

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPLK2.png)

I need a way to choose parts I want to display like

```
01:02:02
02:01:100
128:02:12
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh531.png)
or

```
01:02
02:01
128:02
```

I tried  suggested solutions in similar questions without success like

```
select substring(column_name, '[^:]*$') from table_name;
```

how could this work?

Comment: Without using regexp (probably faster): `select array_to_string((string_to_array(column_name, ':'))[1:3],':') from table_name;` Here `[1:3]` are first and last elements indexes.

Comment: this also worked:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first three parts, you can use

```
SELECT substring(column_name FROM '^(([^:]*:){2}[^:]*)')
FROM table_name;
```

For the first two parts, omit the `{2}`. For the first four parts, make it `{3}`.

Comment: yes perfect, worked straight ahead. thx both for the help. will edit my question to be more readable

Answer (score 0):

try `split_part` (where you can specify which occurrence you want), eg:

```
t=# with s as (select '128:02:12:02'::text m) select split_part(m,':',1),split_part(m,':',2) from s;
 split_part | split_part
------------+------------
 128        | 02
(1 row)
```

Comment: yes it works but I need to have the output in the same cell with ':' between the selected parts. split_part->128:02.  so I end with one column again

Comment: for 128:02:12:02 and think of it as a string all the parts are in the same cell of the column. the output will be again a string 128:02 in one cell of one column. hope my answer clears things

Comment: no, it does not. Please update your question with readable sample or expected result, please formatted text